Problems loading a model saved in .h5 after upgrading Tensorflow from 2.15.0 to 2.17.0
I created an LSTM model with the tensorflow library version 2.15.0.
I now have to use the model created in a new project, but in this project I have to use all the updated libraries and also the last python version, so I had to make some changes, these are the crucial updates:




FROM
TO




python
3.11.5
3.12.6


h5py
3.9.0
3.11.0


keras
2.15.0
3.5.0


numpy
1.24.3
1.26.4


pandas
2.0.3
2.2.2


tensorboard
2.15.2
2.17.2


tensorflow
2.15.0
2.17.0


tensorflow-intel
2.15.0
2.17.0



In the new project the only use of tensorflow that I make use of is for the load_model, and I do it like this:
def load_model_and_hyperparams(model_name):

    logging.info(f"Loading model and parameters for '{model_name}'")

    try:
        model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "python", model_name, f"{model_name}.h5")
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path) 

        params_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "python", model_name, "_hyperparameters.json")
        with open(params_path, 'r') as f:
            params = json.load(f)

        logging.info(f"Model and parameters successfully loaded for {model_name}")
        return model, params

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to load model or parameters for {model_name}. Error: {e}")
        raise

and this is the error i get:

18-09-2024 16:28:08 INFO:Loading model and parameters for 'modello_canale'
18-09-2024 16:28:08 ERROR:Failed to load model or parameters for modello_canale. 
Error: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to LSTM: {'time_major': False}

I tried loading the model into the old version of tensorflow and removing the time_major attribute from the model's configuration stored in the HDF5(.h5) file.
According to what I know this should be an example of the structure of an h5 file:

/
├── model_weights (group)
│   ├── layer_1 (group)
│   │   └── weights (dataset)
│   └── layer_2 (group)
│       └── weights (dataset)
├── model_config (group or dataset)
│   └── attributes (key-value pairs like 'time_major')
└── training_config (group)
    └── optimizer (dataset)

Instead of retraining or recreating the model, this approach should directly modify the stored model configuration in the HDF5 file to remove the invalid parameter, allowing the model to be loaded without errors.
I don't know what else to try. My goal would be to remove time_major without having to recreate the model in version 2.17.0.
